# Debug Target keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu, visual-studio-2015

A tl;dr first: I simply want to hide all toolbars in Visual Studio and be able to choose "Debug Target" by a keyboard shortcut and/or in the Menu Bar. Is this possible?

Longer explanation: In my Xamarin Project I'm debugging on multiple devices including a tablet, phone and some emulators, so I have these choices when selection a "Debug Target" from the "standard" toolbar:

[image: Debug targets]

Since I don't like using my mouse, and prefer cleaning up my GUI as much as possible, I want to remove this toolbar and to the same thing via a keyboard/menu bar, but I can't find anything like "Debug Target" anywhere else. I've tried looking through all the menus, and I have also browsed through the Customize menus to add it myself.

It seems to me that "Debug Target" is some kind of submenu with multiple "magic" buttons/menus under it, looks like this in the customize dialog:

[image: this]

I'm guessing I probably need the `cmdidDebugTargetDevices` and/or some of the other entries here, but I can't find them using the "Add Command" button. I've been through all the different categories looking for `cmdidDebugTargetDevices` without luck, and I'm at a loss for what to try next.

Comment: did you find a way around this?

Comment: Nope, sadly I never did.

Answer (score 0):

Select appropriate process in Task Manager to debug with Microsoft Visual Studio or any other debugger.
[image: debugging windows with visual studio]

Comment: Sorry, not exactly what I'm looking for, but thanks for the info, didn't know about that :) My processes are started by visual studio as either an emulator, or external process on an Android or iOS device